# How to add lightning component to a navigation menu of community site

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community, community-builder

HI All i have created a custom lightning component and i want to add it to navigation bar of community site. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add component directly on ,  However you can include on page and later add it to navigation menu or use flows.  Check more details on [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder.htm)  and available [navigation types](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/07/advanced-community-navigation-components).

Thanks